# C++11: pointers to member function using std::function::target()

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I know this is already a long discussed topic, but I couldn't yet find an answer that satisfies me.

Question in short: even using the C++11's function::target() capabilities, is it not possible to pass member function pointers to c-style methods?

The following code will not work: the invocation to mbf.target() will return 0 and thus a SEGFAULT is produced. And I don't understand why, because I bind the member function to a generic function object, so the type should be fine.

What am I doing wrong or am I trying to do something impossible?

```
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

typedef void (*CBType)(int, int);
CBType myCB = 0;

void regCallback(CBType cb)
{
    myCB = cb;
}

class A
{
public:
    void memberCB(int a, int b) {}

    void registerCallback()
    {
        auto mbMem = mem_fn(&A::memberCB);
        function<void(int,int)> mbf =
            bind(mbMem, *this, placeholders::_1, placeholders::_2);
        regCallback(*mbf.target<void(*)(int,int)>());
    }
};


int main()
{
    A inst;
    inst.registerCallback();
}
```

Comment: There is a difference between `typedef void (*CBType)(int, int);` and `typedef void (A::*CBType)(int, int);`. I think you are messing up there. Remember that the type of `&A::memberCB` is `void (A::*)(int, int)` and not `void (*)(int, int)`. Your code doesn't compile, Can you give a compiling code?

Comment: Right, I added the the header file and namespace. Then it compiles using g++ and the compiler flag "-std=c++0x"

Comment: Impossible. `target` is meant for retrieving a function pointer that you previously stored there. It does no magic and cannot produce gold^Wfunction pointers out of lead^Wanything else. You can forget about `target` here; it has a completely different (and rather uncommon) use case.

Comment: lol awesome, that answers my question, thanks to all replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your member function is not of type `void (*)(int, int)` it is of type `void (A::*)(int, int)`. Therefore `target` returns `nullptr` since you try to cast to the wrong type. I would recommend just making `CBType` a `std::function<void(int, int)>`.

Comment: That's interesting. So a declaration "function<void(int,int)> mbf = ..." still somehow will keep an internal type reference to the class and cannot abstract the type to the non-member-pointer?

Comment: Even if it was possible technically it can't be right. Functionality of the class function depends on the object it's bound to, it's part of its context.

Comment: Yeah, of course. But that's why I wanna bind the object to the function. But seems I have a too high-level view of std::function's capabilities.

Comment: Following the std::function approach, will you ever be able to unregister the callback?

Comment: @AlexDarsonik, you *can* unregister a `std::function` but it is a nightmare. You basically have to have a`std::unordered_map` and pre-hash the function object using `target_type().hash_code()` and `target<FunType>()`.  Getting the correct `FunType` is the exciting bit however and requires all kinds of template magic.  Have successfully implemented it but it was a lot of work.

Comment: @MattClarkson let me know if you're up to share :)

Comment: @AlexDarsonik, I have been finding more and more caveats in the code, like binding virtual functions, etc, etc. It's actually much easier (and standards compliant) to just return a cookie like other unregister callback questions have suggested