# Pointer to class member function as an argument to external function

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I'm trying to implement some class methods to OpenGL libraries but I have troubles with pointers to functions. Anyway, let's say we have C++ code:

```
int funct1(int x){
    return x*x;
}
class foo{
public:
    int funct2(int x){
        return x*x;
    }
};
int conv(int (*f)(int)){
    return f(1);
}
int main(){
    conv(funct1);
    foo bar;
    conv(funct2);
}
```

I do realise that funct2 is internal method of foo class, but trying to change conv(funct2) to something like conv(bar.funct2) gives error like:

```
argument of type ‘int (foo::)(int)’ does not match ‘int (*)(int)’
```

I was trying to find help in other posts like that - but always it was very complicated. Can someone post here changed and working code here?

Comment: The reason that all other code pieces are complicated is just that: there is no simple solution. You fundamentally cannot do this. A member function pointer cannot be converted to a free function pointer. End of story. Sorry.

Comment: Non-static member functions take `this` as a hidden argument. It should work with static member functions though.

Comment: if you are ok with using C++11, changing types, using `std::function` and maybe lambdas, then you can achieve it. But with your type constraints, it cannot be done (as @Konrad has stated)

Comment: This cannot be solved using C-Style function pointers, it can be solved using [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found nice way to solve this problem:

```
class MyClass;
static MyClass* ptr;
class MyClass{
void Func(){something;}
static void Func2(){ptr->Func();}
void RunFunc(){
ptr=this;
RunningExternalFunction(Func2);
}
};
```

Voila!

Answer (score 1):

declare funct2 as static

```
int funct1(int x){
return x*x;
}
class foo{
public:
static int funct2(int x){
return x*x;
}
};
int conv(int (*f)(int)){
return f(1);
}
int main(){
conv(funct1);
foo bar;
conv(foo::funct2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler supports c++11 you can do the following:

```
#include<functional>

int funct1(int x){
    return x*x;
}
class foo{
public:
    int funct2(int x){
        return x*x;
    }
};

int conv(int (*f)(int)){
    return f(1);
}

int main(){
    conv(funct1);
    foo bar;
    auto boundFunct2 = std::function<int(int)>(std::bind(&foo::funct2,bar,std::placeholders::_1));
    conv(boundFunct2.target<int(int)>());
}
```

Basically, you're binding funct2 to an instance of the class, namely bar, then creating a function object back out of that. In order for it to make the signature expected by conv(), you call the target member on the function object.

The nice thing is you don't have to change any of the functions or classes, which I'm assuming you can't as they're probably openGL library objects.

Comment: temp.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
temp.cpp:21:10: error: ‘boundFunct2’ does not name a type
temp.cpp:22:10: error: ‘boundFunct2’ was not declared in this scope
temp.cpp:22:29: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’

Sorry man, your code doesn't work.

Comment: It compiles on msvc2010. Your compiler needs to support c++11 for it to compile.

Comment: This code segfaults for me (g++ 4.8.3). The result of `target()` is a null pointer

Comment: This is discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521644/c11-pointers-to-member-function-using-stdfunctiontarget), so this code doesn't work and isn't fixable.